# I am not able to get google map through ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

This is my code for Map component which is not rendering the map.
I have my root component where I am calling this component.When I remove this Map component from root component then everything works.

```
 import React from "react";
    import {GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker} from "react-google-maps";

    export class Maps extends React.Component{
        render()
        {
            const mapContainer = <div style = {{height: '100%' ,width : '100%'}}> </div>
            return(
                <GoogleMapLoader
                    containerElement={ mapContainer }
                    googleMapElement={
                        <GoogleMap 
                            defaultZoom={15}
                            defaultCenter={this.props.center}
                            options={{streetViewControl:false, mapTypeControl:false}}>
                        </GoogleMap>
                    } />
                );
        }
    }
```

This is my html code which is displaying the map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&key=AIzaSyD86429NQEmUFubzkZeLQV_kywQWgNyoUw"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error in console window of browser

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Maps`.
    at invariant (bundle.js:1916)
    at createFiberFromElement (bundle.js:22993)
    at reconcileSingleElement (bundle.js:24794)
    at reconcileChildFibers (bundle.js:24898)
    at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (bundle.js:25022)
    at reconcileChildren (bundle.js:25013)
    at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:25149)
    at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:25121)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:25495)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:27486)
```

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yes I will add that error

Comment: is `this.props.center` defined ? Try console logging it ?

Comment: Ok, I looked at the library.. Is there anything as `GoogleMapLoader` in it ??

Comment: instead of using this.props.center I used it as {location} where const location ={
   lat:40.7575285,
   lng:-73.9884469
  }  I declared this in map component itself. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<GoogleMapLoader
    containerElement={ mapContainer }
    googleMapElement={ () =>
        <GoogleMap 
            defaultZoom={15}
            defaultCenter={this.props.center}
            options={{streetViewControl:false, mapTypeControl:false}}>
        </GoogleMap>
    } 
 />
```

You can't pass JSX to props, you must use a closure so that the JSX is interpreted.

Comment: Then you've got another issue. Nevertheless this issue would've come up too. Looking at it...

Comment: How are you importing the `Maps` component? It should be 

`import { Maps } from "../the/path/here";`

because you're not exporting Maps as the `default export`

Comment: import { Maps } from "./components/Maps";  I have the Maps component here.

Comment: I don't see anything in the `react-google-maps` documentation for `GoogleMapLoader`

ref: https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/